# Reverse Zen Coding

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, sizzle, emmet

I'm writing a JavaScript unit test suite and one of the features I'd like to add is the ability to assert that a certain element and its children match a given HTML structure.

My first idea is to use jQuery (well, Sizzle) and ask that users write [Zen Code](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) statements to make assertions. My first question is *"Has this been done before? Can I steal it?"*. If not, is there a specification printed anywhere for how to parse a Zen Code statement? Are there any shortcuts I could make, given the power of Sizzle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26959048/496176

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get there with sizzle + http://api.jquery.com/size/.

The example Zen Code query is "div#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a". Testing if a page has that same structure in jQuery would be as easy as $("div#page > div.logo + ul#navigation > li > a").size() == 5.

Unless your users are already familiar with Zen Code, tests with an API like assertSelects(selector, number_of_returned_items) should be cozier.

Comment: That's good, but it breaks down on slightly complicated expressions like `div>(ul>li)+p>a`

Comment: nickf: I'm not suggesting css selectors can do everything zen code can do, only that they are sufficient for telling if a node and it's children have a certain structure.