# Generate Emmet code from HTML - reverse action

Tags: javascript, emmet

I am talking about Emmet.io (former Zen Coding).

Is there JavaScript code or jQuery plugin that does that in reverse?

Example:

```
emmet('ul > li*3') => '<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>'
```

I want something like this:

```
emmet('<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>') => 'ul > li*3'
```

Comment: This is kinda tough because, there can be many types. Whereas the former is only one.

Comment: just wondering, why would you want to turn markup into emmet code? You basically want to reserve back what you have already done?

Comment: you could write a regular exp and the loop through those results and spit out what you want that way.

Comment: @JamieHutber That would be a worst case algo! :(

Comment: @JamieHutber regexp is overkill, jquery could do it easily and i can spend few days really writing it myself and i will if i don't get answers by tomorrow. reason is, this is a great way to store templates, and that has to be revers-able process.

Comment: We have the Sizzle selector. And with the `.size()` I guess we might be able to achieve it. Check this question (it seems similar): *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864261/reverse-zen-coding*.

Comment: @iggy fair enough. but JS can do regex ;)

Comment: @Iggy did you write anything to do this you could share?

Comment: @AdamHeath yes i did, you can find it here: [link](http://pocketbytes.net/0981_squabby/sample/)